# ¿Como puedo hacer que el usuario no pueda extender (redimensionar) el formulario en C#?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo hago que el usuario no pueda extender (redimensionar) el formulario?

[image]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con extender un formulario? ¿Que no pueda heredar de la clase? ¿Que no pueda cambiar el tamaño? ¿Que no pueda añadir elementos?

Comment: Esta pregunta está muy, pero muy mal formulada, pero me sorprende más que tenga respuestas con votos positivos, y de usuarios experimentados que saben que no se debería responder.

Comment: @Shaz pero se entiendo lo que plantea, pone la imagen de un form y hace referencia a extender, queda claro que se refiere a cambiar las dimensiones del form. Igual si hubiera dado respuesta algunas preguntas de los comentarios seguro ayudaba a clarificar

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Asi es bro

Answer (score 4):

Mira en la propiedad [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx)

```
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

También puedes quitar los botones de minimizar y maximizar:

```
form1.MaximizeBox = false;
form1.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Esto lo puedes hacer desde las propiedades como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Propiedades del Windows.Forms]

Comment: creo que todos miramos la misma respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970262/disable-resizing-of-a-windows-forms-form

Answer (score 0):

Si haces referencia a los bordes del formulario para que no se pueda cambiar el tamaño del form, entonces asigna la propiedad

[Form.FormBorderStyle Propiedad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle?view=netframework-4.8)

con el valor `FixedSingle`

```
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

por supuesto realiza esto desde el diseñador

Comment: ¿Y si no hace referencia a los bordes del formulario para que no se pueda cambiar el tamaño?

Comment: porque un negativo si aconsejo lo mismo que la otra pregunta donde le pusieron positivo ? solo que respondimos al mismo tiempo

Comment: porque consideran que tienes demasiados puntos

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no entendi el custionamiento, para que no se pueda redimensionar hay que cambiar la propiedad de los bordes, no importa si hizo o no referencia a esto, es la forma en que entiendo debe realizarse

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no habla de redimensionar, habla de extender. Extender puede referirse a la clase del formulario, como puede referirse a el tamaño del formulario… también puede referirse (por usuarios noveles) a añadir más controles al formulario o incluso puede referirse a algo de lo que no seamos conscientes. La pregunta es imposible de responder adecuadamente a no ser que se responda por casualidad, y aún así no es útil por contenido ni por título ya que ningún usuario experimentado buscará esta información con estos términos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster entiendo es un usuario novato, crees que conoce todo el lexico como para que escribiera `redimensionar` a la primera, hay que tambien entender un poco entre lineas. Crees que todos los usuario que usan el grupo son experimentados? ayuda tambien a los demas sin penalizarlos tan duro

Comment: Pero no podemos "*entender entre líneas*", porque entonces responderemos "*entre líneas*" y será una respuesta que deba interpretarse "*entre líneas*". Si un usuario espera recibir ese tipo de ayuda difusa y neblinosa, le sale más a cuenta contactar con una pitonisa que con un experto en programación.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster pero porque interpretas como entendi la pregunta? yo la entendi correctamente, pone la imagen de un form y hace referencia a extender, queda claro que se refiere a cambiar las dimensiones del form, igual si me hubiera equivocado no pasa nada, elimino la respuesta y eso es todo

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que entendiste la pregunta correctamente? Todo lo que mencionas son conjeturas, no certezas.